# Way in XForms to output element name

Tags: xforms

I have a `xf:repeat` over a set of elements that aren't all the same name, using a selector like `<xf:repeat ref="root/foo/*">`. I've been trying to make it print a label for each element that gets displayed, based on the name. But the following doesn't work:

```
<xf:output ref="name(.)" />
```

Neither does anything that references the specific node:

```
<xf:output ref="name(root/foo/bar)" />
```

Does XForms support outputting the current element's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `xf:output/@value` instead of `xf:output/@ref`